# How Do I Add a DropDownList In My View From my Local Database in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a DropDownList for my View in my MVC Web Application from my Local Database in which I've stored ***Games with an Id, a GameName, GameDescription, GameImage, Genre and a ReleaseYear.***

The only value I want in my DropDownList is the **GameName** data from my Database.

I'm using another model called Highscores.cs in my View but I want to use the Games.cs model here together with the Highscores model and create the DropDownList from the Games.cs model with the GameName value. I've tried to search for the solution but nothing works which of which I've tried.

Here is my Games.cs model:

```
public class Games
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string GameName { get; set; }
        public string GameDescription { get; set; }
        public string GameImage { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseYear {get; set;}
    }
```

Here is the View I want to create my DropDownList in:

```
@model Inlämningsuppgift_Nummer_2.Models.Highscores

<h1>New</h1>

<h4>Register New Highscore</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="New">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Game" class="control-label"></label>
                @* I want my DropDownList here from my model Games with the value of GameName *@

                @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Highscores.Game, new SelectList(Model.Games.GameName, "Select Game"))*@

                <span asp-validation-for="Game" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public IActionResult New()
        {
            CommonViewModel commonViewModel = new CommonViewModel();

            var gamesList = commonViewModel.Games.GameName.ToList();

            return View(gamesList);
        }
```

And here is my CommonViewModel:

```
public class CommonViewModel
    {
        public Highscores Highscores { get; set; }
        public Games Games { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do you use an entity framework? Pls post how you created a model for the view.

Comment: @Sergey Yes I used Entity Framework to create the database Games via migrations

Comment: @Sergey Thanks for any help in advance! I used a local database and created a table via the Package Manager Console using Entity Framework via migrations

Comment: Could you post your view action pls?

Comment: @Sergey Of course, I'll add it to the Question

Comment: Thanks. Can you post a CommonViewModel too, pls?

Comment: @Sergey Absolutely! Thanks Sergey! I'll add it aswell to the question, thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a key reference to games model from Highscores model. Could you also post the Highscores model.  Are you trying to update the highscores model that contain a games name, you would like to have a dropdownlist of game name selection from your view?

Answer (score 0):

Im very confused with your models cause `commonViewModel.Games` is an object of type `Games` and `Games` had the `GameName` property wich is a `string`, so the what does the .ToList() there?

Also your View receives a Model of type `Highscores` but your controller is sending the `gamesList` object. (wich is a List of string????)

I made some changes toy your code in order to try to help you.

```
public IActionResult New()
    {
        CommonViewModel commonViewModel = new CommonViewModel();
        commonViewModel.Games = new dbContext().Games.ToList(); // commonViewModel.Games mus be a List<Games> to work.
        
        return View(commonViewModel);
    }
```

Also you will need to change your View model to `@model Inlämningsuppgift_Nummer_2.Models.CommonViewModel`